# Private Catalog Templates are not Showing up in Rancher

Tags: rancher, gogs

I currently have a Rancher Server, which has a Gogs repository. This repository is tied back into Rancher for private catalog items. I have pushed Rancher catalog templates to this repository, however Rancher does not recognize the templates and I continue to get the message "There are no compatible templates." Any help on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated. Also, I have used a Rancher template generator to generate templates, along with known working catalog templates to try and fix this issue but it hasn't corrected the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The git repository needs to be accessible by `rancher/server` to clone locally. Can you please check if you can manually clone the repository inside the `rancher/server` container in a temporary directory(`/tmp`)?

Also check the `rancher/server` container logs for any pointers.

Another thing to checkout is if your catalog has any errors? You can clone the [community-catalog](https://github.com/rancher/community-catalog) on your Gogs server and add it in `rancher/server` to see if it works. If that also doesn't work that means there is problem accessing your Gogs server.

If you want a simple catalog item that works for sure, you can use mine too: https://github.com/leodotcloud/test-triple-catalog